# Dependencies of the referenced assembly don't get included in VS

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I'm trying to debug a function in a main project which gets referenced through a helper app. This app is normally gets deployed as a NuGet package but while working locally I need to remove that package reference and add an assembly reference. The main project also uses some of this helper app's dependencies. Using the helper app as a **NuGet** package, the main app seems to include these dependencies but when I switch to an **assembly reference**, it won't see them. I tried closing and opening the solution, cleaning the solution and publishing the helper app in various methods. Nothing seems to work so far.

Does anyone have any idea how I can make visual studio get the dependencies of the referenced assembly?

---

The project dependencies are like this:

The Main Project:

- Foo
- Bar.Helper

Bar.Helper Project:

- Blah
- Pew

And the main project has `using` statements all over the place that references namespaces under `Blah`.

Comment: `I need to remove that package reference and add an assembly reference` no you don't, and can't. Why do you want this? That's the real problem. What you describe is how Visual Studio always worked, it's not a bug. Adding a reference to an assembly doesn't add or even know about its dependencies. NuGet packages were created to add all dependencies automatically

Comment: Do I just need to add the assembly reference and it should work?

Comment: No, I said it won't work. If you want to include all transient dependencies automatically you should use packages. Why are you trying to avoid them ?

Comment: Because there are too many...

Comment: Which means the references you need to add will be a **lot** more. You don't have to manually install packages anyway, `dotnet restore` or Visual Studio itself will restore them automatically. You don't have to add indirect dependencies either, just the root packages. Visual Studio itself will add and restore all indirect dependencies

Comment: If you build a .NET Core / .NET 5+ application, you'll find all dependencies in `obj/project.asset.json`. You'll see that .NET found *and* restored a *lot* of indirect dependencies automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my question, all I needed to do was to add the referenced assembly's `.csproj` file as a project reference to my main project. This is only possible if you have access to the codebase and luckily I did.

You'll need to right click the Solution in the Solution Explorer and then click on **Add -> Existing Project** and then navigate to the project's folder and pick the **csproj** file.